# ActionScript 3: Adding multiple instances of the same object to the stage and removing each separately

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild, animate-cc

I have a piece of code adding three insances of the same MovieClip to the stage. I also added **MouseEvent.CLICK** listener. Once any of the MovieClips gets clicked, I want it to be removed from the stage. My problem is, whenever any of the elements gets clicked, only the last one gets removed and when I click again on a different instance, I'm getting:

*ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.*

I added these three MovieClips to an array, but I don't know how I can properly identify which instance got clicked and remove only the said instance.

This is the excerpt of code I have:

```js
var myMC: SomeMC;
var myArray: Array = [];


function Loaded(e: Event): void {
 
 for (var i: int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  
 myMC = new SomeMC();

 myMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
 
 myMC.y = 50;
 myMC.x = 50 * i;
 
 addChild(myMC);
 
 myArray.push(myMC);

 }  
}

function  imageClicked(e: MouseEvent){
 
  // Only the last instance gets removed.
  
 e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(myMC);
  
  }
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Loaded` function you create 3 instances of the object, but by doing:

`myMC = new SomeMC();`

you overwrite reference. In first iteration `myMC` is 1st one, in 2nd 2nd one, etc...

Then in `imageClicked` you're trying to remove it. 1st time it's working because it's referencing the last object, but after you removed it from stage it won't work anymore.

How about changing `e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(myMC);` to `e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);` ? That should remove clicked one.